# Shuffle out a specific object from array

Tags: java, arrays, object, shuffle

I have an array storing different mammals, the objects stored in the mammals array are such as dogs, cats etc which I've created with this code:

```
Mammals obj = new Cats();
Mammals obj = new Dogs();

etc....
```

Now I want to shuffle out a specific object from the array, just to print it out. Let's say I want to print out a cat object from this printCat-method - how can the code below be modified so that I make sure that only cat objects are shuffled out?

```
public static void printCat() {

    Mammals item;

    int index = shuffleArray.nextInt(mammals.size());
    item = mammals.get(index);

    System.out.println(item);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "shuffle out"? Can you describe in terms of how the `shuffleArray` would look before and after that operation?

Comment: Slight thing I'd like to point out -- if the `Mammals` instances are only meant to represent a single mammal, you should call the class `Mammal`. It will make your code easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void printCat() {
    Mammal result;

    do 
    {
        int index = shuffleArray.nextInt(mammals.size());
        result = mammals.get(index);
    } while (!(result instanceof Cat));

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

A word of warning... ensure the mammals collection contains a cat before running this, or you'll be stuck in an infinite loop. You could also consider modifying this so you won't select the same Mammal multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
if(item instanceof Cat){
    System.out.println(item);
}else{
    //it is not cat
}
```